# How to handle custom events?

Tags: c++, events

I've tried the following:

event.h

```
 class event : public QEvent
 {
 public:
 int Status1;
 int Status2;
 static const QEvent::Type StatusChange = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(1155);
 //Konstruktor
 event(int Status1, int Status2)
 : QEvent(StatusChange) {this->Status1 = Status1; this->Status2= Status2; }
 }
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include event.h
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

      void Dialog::on_pushButton2_clicked()
      {
      QWidget *mainWidget;
      foreach(QWidget *widget, QApplication::allWidgets())
      {
        if(widget->windowTitle().toStdString()=="MainWindow") mainWidget=widget;
      }          
      event::event *e = new event::event(1, 1);
      qApp->postEvent(mainWidget, e); 
      }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
 #include event.h
 void MainWindow::customEvent(event::event *ev)
 {
 ui->label_2->show();
 }
```

It's just a test setup so I'll modify the `customEvent`.
Problem is that the `customEvent` is not triggered at all.
When changing event to `QEvent` it works fine.
Is there a other way to change the arguments of `QEvent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QObject` has a method called `void QObject::customEvent( QEvent* ev )` your method is different, because you replace `QEvent` with `event::event`. You are not replacing but overloading. When Qt calls `MainWindow::customEvent`, `QEvent`version is called.

You need to modify your method to accept `QEvent` argument. Then you can cast the argument to know if this argument is typical `QEvent` or your custom class.

Comment: So you're saying i should give customEvent the argument QEvent? But how can i get the parameter i defined for event? e.g. Status1.

Comment: `event* evt = dynamic_cast< event* >( ev ); if ( evt ) { /* code for your custom event class here */ evt->Status1 = 10; }`